# check or uncheck all checkboxes based on a condition

Tags: jquery

I have this html

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.Options)
  {
     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="selectedObjects" noneoption=@(item.OptionText=="None of the above" ? "true" : "false") id="@(Model.QuestionNo)_@(item.OptionNumber)_chk" value="@item.OptionNumber" onchange="checkBoxChangeNone(this);" /> 
   }
```

My condition

1.when a user click on a checkbox if its contain ***noneoption=true*** then all other checkboxes are unchecked.

2.When a user click on checkbox that contain  ***noneoption=false*** if a checkbox with ***noneoption=true*** checked it must unchecked.

i have written this JS but its not working.

```
        function checkBoxChangeNone(checkbox) {
        var noneoption = $(checkbox).attr('noneoption');
        var checkid = '#' + checkbox.id;
        var splitstr = checkbox.id.split('_');
        var formid = $('#myform_' + splitstr[0]); 
        if (noneoption == 'true') {
            $('input[name$=_selectedobjects]:checked').each(function () { 
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });
            $(checkid).prop("checked", true); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's not really HTML. Since your question is purely about HTML, I would advise that you edit your alleged HTML to be the rendered HTML source, which would:
A) allow people who are not familiar with that framework answer the question
B) rule out that the problem is with generating the markup
C) make it easier for others to create a test page to work out a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cCqfM/1/

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("noneoption") == "false") {
        $("input[type=checkbox][noneoption=true]").attr("checked", false);
    }
    else if ($(this).attr("noneoption") == "true") {
        $("input[type=checkbox][noneoption=false]").attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 This is the proper logic, but OP's use of [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is preferable to your use of `attr`.

Answer (score 0):

use class to group the checkboxes, and set the attributes like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.all').click(function(){
    $('input.answer').attr("checked", "checked");
  });
  $('input.none').click(function(){
    $('input.answer').removeAttr("checked");
    $('input.all').removeAttr("checked");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="answer">A. Number 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="answer">B. Number 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="answer">C. Number 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="all">D. All<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="none">E. None<br/>
</body>
</html>
```